# Couple service related "bugs"

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode4.6

I've written an application that can be invoked as a service (by right-clicking a file in Finder and selecting to open it with my application), but there are a couple of unwanted side-effects when doing this.

Example of service target method:

```
- (void)doSomething:(NSPasteboard *)pboard userData:(NSString *)userData error:(NSString **)error {
    NSArray *files = [pboard propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType];
    NSLog(@"Selected file(s): %@", files);
    [self.anotherWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}
```

<strike>1) When the application is launched this way (even if already open in debug mode), I seem unable to access other windows/controls from the doSomething function. The above attempt to show "anotherWindow", for example, produces no errors, but doesn't "do" anything. According to the stack trace, when inspected from -doSomething, all gui components have values 0x0000000000000000 - yet the application is displayed and fully functional. It's only from -doSomething that I cannot reach them. "self" also has a different value when inspected from -doSomething versus -applicationDidFinishLaunching. I'm not sure how or why -doSomething is acquiring a different self/AppDelegate with uninitialized components.</strike> Seemingly fixed by [NSApp setServicesProvider:self];

2) I am not clear on how the system decides which copy of the application to launch when the service is invoked, but it usually doesn't pick the one I want. I have a copy in /Debug, a copy in /Release, a copy on my desktop... and if I delete one, it opens the file with another one instead (some sort of fallback-chain?). How do I configure the service (in code or thru .plist) to open a specific version/location of this app? But this is a dev machine. If I release a distributable which installs to /Applications, do I ever really need to worry about this?

Comment: I added NSAlerts to -doSomething and to -applicationDidFinishLaunching. The one in -applicationDidFinishLaunching gets fired first, and I see the main application window (self.mainWindow). Then the one in -doSomething pops up, and prints that self.mainWindow is (null). Despite the fact that I can see and interact with it. Is -doSomething not running within the same instance?

Answer (score 0):

1) Double-check your XIB to makes sure that you've got everything hooked up correctly and then try launching the app with a breakpoint set at the `NSLog` above and verify that `self.anotherWindow` points at what you want.  If, for some reason, the breakpoint isn't firing, trying adding an:

```
NSLog( @"Window: %@", self.anotherWindow);
```

To make sure everything is initialized and hooked up

2) The system uses `Launch Services` to determine which version of the application to launch.   Often it is the version most recently added to the system (which will cause the `Launch Services` database to be modified), but it is possible, depending on how your system is configured, that it won't be the version you expect.

You can manually inquire and modify the launch services database using:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister
```

(yeah, really long path).   If you use the `-dump` option, that'll give you all of the data in the system (pipe into a file and search through it to get a better idea what's going on).  If you search of the bundle id, you'll see all of the entries for the app.   Generally, most recent wins, but you can force a reload (instructions below).

If you just want to force a reload based on a a particular binary, use the `-f` flag and the path to the application:

```
..../lsregister -f /Applications/Foo.app
```

You can also use `-u` to explicitly unregister something.

Hopefully this will give you an idea what's going on here.

Comment: If I distribute this app to others, what's the best way to make sure I  register the service correctly? I'm currently doing [NSApp setServicesProvider:appDelegate] and NSUpdateDynamicServices() in the code, but it obviously isn't directing the OS to the version of the app that has most recently executed those commands.

Comment: NSLog(@"Window: %@", self.anotherWindow); prints Window: (null). NSLog(@"%@", self) prints "<AppDelegate: 0x7fadeac2abc0>" from -doSomething, and prints "<AppDelegate: 0x7fadea85dbc0>" from -applicationDidFinishLaunching. Different instances of self?

Comment: @Eric For the question about making sure the service registers correctly, only one app with a particular bundle ID should be on the user's machine at once.   When the App is installed, the OS will read the Info.plist and register any services as appropriate (of course, you have the Services configuration to deal with as well)

Comment: @Eric Based on your `NSLog`s, it sounds like you have separate AppDelegate instances in your apps, either separate processes, or you are creating a second delegate.  Add a breakpoint in your AppDelegate creation code and check the stack trace and the process info for each of the two calls to see where they are coming from.

Comment: I added breakpoints, and in the stack trace under Thread 1, 0 -[AppDelegate.. ], self = (AppDelegate *), when inspected from -doSomething, it shows that all gui components have values 0x0000000000000000, which I assume is not a good sign. In either case they seem to take basically the same init route. start->main->NSApplicationMain->.. the next 2 steps differ slightly. But I never wrote any initialization code per-se, and I haven't explicitly created a second delegate anywhere. Basically created a new project in xcode and began writing code at the applicationDidFinishLaunching stage.

Comment: @Eric you're going to have to do some investigation and add much more detailed information to your original question about how these are called.   This looks like a XIB problem and/or an initialization issue, so make sure you check for the outlets for the window, etc. in your XIB.

Comment: I think I've found the problem:
AppDelegate *receiver;
receiver = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
[NSApp setServicesProvider:receiver];
NSUpdateDynamicServices();
I should be using self.